# Why isn't my button finding the input value of this input text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click my button and console.log the value of the input text field, it just shows blank. Why is that? My code looks correct...

```
<div class="btn btn-default btn-xs col-md-2">
    <input class="form-control input-sm col-md-2 " type="text" name="lfdcontainerfield" placeholder="Container #" id="lfdcontainerfield">        <br>
    <!--
    <input class="form-control input-sm col-md-2 " type="text" placeholder="File #" id="lfdfilenumber">        <br>
    <input class="form-control input-sm col-md-2 " type="text" placeholder="Terminal Code" id="lfdterminal">        <br>
    -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm col-md-12" id='lfdsubmit'><strong>Submit</strong></button>   <br>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {

    let y = $("#lfdcontainerfield").val();
    $("#lfdsubmit").click(() => {
        //e.preventDefault();

        let lfd_container = $("#lfdcontainerfield").val();
        //let lfd_filenumber = $("#lfdfilenumber");  //reserved
        //let lfd_terminal = $("#lfdterminal");  //reserved

        console.log(lfd_container);
        console.log(y);


        LFD_SearchContainer(lfd_container)
        .then(container => {
            //console.log("This is .then : " + container);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //console.log(error);
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: LFD_SearchContainer is undefined....

Comment: You have two `console.log()` calls. Which is the one you're asking about? `console.log(y)` should be blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in this case that `lfd_container` is returning the proper value because you are polling the input for its' value after the button is clicked.
The variable `y` however, is being set before any value is input when the page is loaded. You can see this because it is an empty string. It is retaining that empty value while you are getting the updated value from the input after the click event.

For this code I've commented out your function `LFD_SearchContainer` so that things will run. It's undefined because I don't have its implementation.

```js
$(function() {

    let y = $("#lfdcontainerfield").val();
    $("#lfdsubmit").click(() => {
        //e.preventDefault();

        let lfd_container = $("#lfdcontainerfield").val();
        //let lfd_filenumber = $("#lfdfilenumber");  //reserved
        //let lfd_terminal = $("#lfdterminal");  //reserved

        console.log(lfd_container);
        console.log(y);
        console.log(typeof y);

        //LFD_SearchContainer(lfd_container)
        //.then(container => {
            //console.log("This is .then : " + container);
        //})
        //.catch(error => {
            //console.log(error);
        //});
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn btn-default btn-xs col-md-2">
    <input class="form-control input-sm col-md-2 " type="text" name="lfdcontainerfield" placeholder="Container #" id="lfdcontainerfield">        <br>
    <!--
    <input class="form-control input-sm col-md-2 " type="text" placeholder="File #" id="lfdfilenumber">        <br>
    <input class="form-control input-sm col-md-2 " type="text" placeholder="Terminal Code" id="lfdterminal">        <br>
    -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm col-md-12" id='lfdsubmit'><strong>Submit</strong></button>   <br>
</div>
```

Just for fun this is what it's like if you had a val on page load.

```js
    $(function() {
        let rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
        $("#lfdcontainerfield").val(rand);
        let y = $("#lfdcontainerfield").val();
        $("#lfdsubmit").click(() => {
            //e.preventDefault();

            let lfd_container = $("#lfdcontainerfield").val();
            //let lfd_filenumber = $("#lfdfilenumber");  //reserved
            //let lfd_terminal = $("#lfdterminal");  //reserved

            console.log('The value of lfd_container:  ' + lfd_container);
            console.log('The value of y:  ' + y);

            //LFD_SearchContainer(lfd_container)
            //.then(container => {
                //console.log("This is .then : " + container);
            //})
            //.catch(error => {
                //console.log(error);
            //});
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="btn btn-default btn-xs col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control input-sm col-md-2 " type="text" name="lfdcontainerfield" placeholder="Container #" id="lfdcontainerfield">        <br>
        <!--
        <input class="form-control input-sm col-md-2 " type="text" placeholder="File #" id="lfdfilenumber">        <br>
        <input class="form-control input-sm col-md-2 " type="text" placeholder="Terminal Code" id="lfdterminal">        <br>
        -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm col-md-12" id='lfdsubmit'><strong>Submit</strong></button>   <br>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have 2 logs, the first one should log the input value, but the second one will have an empty string because  **let y = $("#lfdcontainerfield").val();** code never calls and y doesn't have a value. 
Include it in the click event scope and it will be executed on button click.